# Textblock binding property changed not working in UWP

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, localization, xamarin.uwp

I'm trying to achieve a simple "press a button to change the App language and all dependent strings" example. (You can see the whole code at [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/FrancescoBonizzi/UWPLocalization))

In this example I have three `TextBlock` and one button bound to my language Resources:

[image: Resources hierarchy]

And:

```
<StackPanel
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Orientation="Vertical">

    <TextBlock
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="20"
        Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Localized}, Path=[A]}" />
    <TextBlock
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="20"
        Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Localized}, Path=[B]}" />
    <TextBlock
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="20"
        Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Localized}, Path=[C]}" />

    <Button
        x:Name="btnChangeLanguage"
        Margin="10"
        Padding="10"
        Click="btnChangeLanguage_Click"
        Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Localized}, Path=[Change]}" />

</StackPanel>
```

As you can see I expressed the binding of the `TextBlock`(s) with: `Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Localized}, Path=[A]}"`

Localized of type `LocalizedStrings`, and it is a static property of App class:

```
public class LocalizedStrings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly ResourceLoader _resources;
    private readonly LocalizationHelper _localizationHelper;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public LocalizedStrings()
    {
        _resources = ResourceLoader.GetForViewIndependentUse();
        _localizationHelper = App.LocalizationHelper;
        _localizationHelper.OnLocalizationChange += _localizationHelper_OnLocalizationChange;
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return _resources.GetString(key);
        }
    }

    private void _localizationHelper_OnLocalizationChange(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(string.Empty));
    }
}
```

And the most interesting part of `LocalizationHelper` is just:

```
public void ChangeLocalizationTo(string cultureCode)
{
    Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = cultureCode;
    OnLocalizationChange?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(string.Empty));
}
```

Lastly, the code of the MainPage button:

```
private void btnChangeLanguage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (LocalizationHelper.IsCultureItalian(App.LocalizationHelper.GetCurrentLocalizationCode()))
        App.LocalizationHelper.ChangeLocalizationTo("en-US");
    else App.LocalizationHelper.ChangeLocalizationTo("it-IT");
}
```

The bindings **are working correctly**, but they bind **just the first time** and never get updated. So, I start the application I see the strings (also during design time), but when I press the button nothing happens. It seems that the `OnLocalizationChange?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(string.Empty));` (which is called) doesn't let the the application call the property to get the translation. (Note that I used `string.Empty` as property name to notify that all properties in this class are changed)

The "funny" fact is that the same identical example made with WPF works perfectly!

[image: WPF Example]

This makes me think that there are some different behaviors with the two platforms binding logic.

I already tried to put a `Mode=OneWay` binding but it doesn't work.

(You can see the whole code at [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/FrancescoBonizzi/UWPLocalization))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After modify the `PrimaryLanguage`, you need refresh your page manually. Please add the following code into `btnChangeLanguage_Click` method.

```
private void btnChangeLanguage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (LocalizationHelper.IsCultureItalian(App.LocalizationHelper.GetCurrentLocalizationCode()))
        App.LocalizationHelper.ChangeLocalizationTo("en-US");
    else App.LocalizationHelper.ChangeLocalizationTo("it-IT");

    //refresh current page
    Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());
}
```

**Update**

> I'd thought I could avoid reloading the page by relying on binding

If you want to refresh your binding, you could change the page datacontext to the new object, and we need re-write the xaml binding like below.

**Xaml**

```
<StackPanel
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Orientation="Vertical">

    <TextBlock
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="20"
        Text="{Binding [A]}" />
    <TextBlock
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="20"
        Text="{Binding [B]}" />
    <TextBlock
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="20"
        Text="{Binding [C]}" />

    <Button
        x:Name="btnChangeLanguage"
        Margin="10"
        Padding="10"
        Click="btnChangeLanguage_Click"
        Content="{Binding [Change]}" />

</StackPanel>
```

**Code Behind**

```
 public MainPage()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     this.DataContext = new LocalizedStrings();
 }

 private async void btnChangeLanguage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (LocalizationHelper.IsCultureItalian(App.LocalizationHelper.GetCurrentLocalizationCode()))
         App.LocalizationHelper.ChangeLocalizationTo("en-US");
     else App.LocalizationHelper.ChangeLocalizationTo("it-IT");
     await Task.Delay(100); // used to prepare the resource.
     this.DataContext = new LocalizedStrings();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Nico, but this is what I don't want to do, because my page has some navigation parameters. I'd thought I could avoid reloading the page by relying on binding.

Comment: I think, you could get data  `_resources.GetString()` manually after change `PrimaryLanguage`

Comment: Do you mean calling that method for each pair control/string?

Comment: I have updated the case reply with your requirement.

Comment: It works! Last question: why in your opinion there such a different behavior between WPF and UWP?